# MS Access doesn't filter calculated field in Short Date format

Tags: sql, ms-access

In my database, I have a field with the following calculation:

```
AD logon date: IIf([lastLogonDate]>[LLTConverted],[lastLogonDate],[LLTConverted])
```

I filter it using the following criteria:

```
<Date()-60
```

However, when I run the query, it displays dates that are in the last 60 days.

In the source file, lastLogonDate and LLTConverted are set to Short Date format.
I tried setting the AD logon date field's format manually (via Properties) to Short Date. I also tried to use the following code:

```
AD logon date: Format(IIf([lastLogonDate]>[LLTConverted],[lastLogonDate],[LLTConverted]),"dd/mm/yyyy")
```

Furthermore, in the Properties sheet, I set the Data Type to Date with Time. Neither of them worked.

Is there another approach I could use?

EDIT:

Data before filter:

08/01/2021
30/09/2020
24/06/2020
17/06/2020
20/05/2020
17/06/2020
28/02/2020
07/01/2021
10/09/2020
13/11/2019
07/01/2021
01/06/2020
21/05/2020
25/05/2020
08/01/2021
07/01/2021
07/08/2020
18/02/2020
28/02/2020
25/06/2020
07/10/2020
01/04/2019
07/02/2020
28/11/2019
28/10/2020
18/02/2020
07/10/2020

After filter:

08/01/2021
07/01/2021
10/09/2020
07/01/2021
01/06/2020
08/01/2021
07/01/2021
07/08/2020
07/10/2020
01/04/2019
07/02/2020
07/10/2020

Comment: Why is Excel tag selected? I tested this and filter works. Format() function results in a string value, not a true date. Edit question to show sample unformatted data. When you said "Data Type to Date with Time" - I think you meant format because the Data Type is still Date/Time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing up things. DateTime values carry no format, only a value.

Thus, if fields [lastLogonDate] and [LLTConverted] are true DateTime, filtering with Date()-60 cannot fail.

If it does, your fields are most likely *Short Text*, and must have a proper format like yyyy-mm-dd, and they must be converted before comparison:

```
AD logon date: DateValue(IIf(DateValue([lastLogonDate]) > DateValue([LLTConverted]), [lastLogonDate], [LLTConverted]))
```

Comment: When I use the code you suggested, I receive the error: 'Data type mismatch in criteria expression.'
When I use the same formatting in Excel in another database, I can use the same filter in another database.
I don't know whether it helps: in the other database, when I check the source table in Design View, the Data Type is Date/Time. I'm following the same actions in Excel with that table, so this is strange.
Shall I recreate the table perhaps?

Comment: Formatting is only for display. The error you see most likely origins from _Null_ values - but if data are DateTime, DateValue is of no use. However, your filtering indicate a filtering of text values by text "10*". Also, this seems like a query; don't know were Excel comes into play.

Comment: I discovered that I should have used LEFT JOIN between the two tables, not INNER JOIN.  
The suggestion using DateValue also helped, thank you very much!

Comment: Is there a reason the same thing wouldn't work with the filter 'Between Date() And Date()-60'? The error message is: 'Date type mismatch in criteria expression'. I get older dates as a result.

Comment: Try with `Between Date() And DateAdd('d', -60, Date())`.

Comment: I copied the same table using the 'Import the source data into a new table in the current database' option, not with the 'Link to the data source by creating a linked table' option. It let me to manually set the Data Type to Date/Time. Nevertheless, it provides me with the same error. In the original database, I also tried to use the function =IF(B2>0,B2/(8.64*10^11) - 109205,"") instead of using the TIMESTAMP function to convert  the Integer8 format. Even with using the other function, it provides the same error.

Comment: Can't tell. A _DateTime_ field can hold nothing but _Null_ and valid date values, so something else is going on.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is another solution: if I use the INT function in the original Excel table, then it converts the values from date + time to just date. In Access, then I have to use

`IIf([lastLogonDate]>[LLTConverted],[lastLogonDate],[LLTConverted])`

instead of

`DateValue(IIf(DateValue([lastLogonDate]) > DateValue([LLTConverted]), [lastLogonDate], [LLTConverted]))`.